# How to search from one of two tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm using two tables `Offered` and `Joined` in Sql server..

I'm offering a candidate to join in a company.. At the time of offering, I'll mention a joining date.. It'll be stored in `Offered` table, not in `Joined` table..

The candidate can join in different date.. That joining date will be stored in `Joined` table.. This should not update in `Offered` table..

Now I'm creating a report combining both `Offered and Joined Report`.. In that I've a column named `Date of Joining`.. In that column, the date will be from `Offered` table if the candidate is yet to join.. If the candidate joined means, the date will be from `Joined` table.. To choose between to tables, I used function..

```
begin
declare @chk int
declare @JoiningDate datetime
set @chk=0
select @chk=id from MemberJoiningDetails where JobPostingId=@JobPostingId and MemberId=@MemberId
if(@chk != 0)
begin
  select @JoiningDate=JoiningDate from MemberJoiningDetails where JobPostingId=@JobPostingId and MemberId=@MemberId
end
else
begin
  select @JoiningDate=JoiningDate from MemberHiringDetails where JobPostingId=@JobPostingId and MemberId=@MemberId
end
return @JoiningDate
end
```

I saved this function and called the function in select statement..

Now my problem is, I want to create report based on Joining date condition.. For that the `WHERE` condition is passed from C#..

But my doubt is, if the candidate is yet to join, the where condition should check from `Offered` table.. If the candidate is joined me, the where condition should check from `Joined` table.. How to do this..?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking to see if one is empty or not you should just put in into `COALESCE` function. Than inside of function you just select Hire date first, if it is null it will return joining date. This way you don't have to worry if they are hired or not. if i'm reading your tables correctly the query will be as follows.

```
SELECT @JoiningDate = COALESCE(h.JoiningDate, j.JoiningDate)
    FROM MemberJoiningDetails AS j
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberHiringDetails AS h
        ON j.JobPostingId = h.JobPostingId
           AND j.MemberId = h.MemberId
    WHERE j.JobPostingId = @JobPostingId
        AND j.MemberId = @MemberId
```

Comment: When I execute your query, it gets date from first table given inside `COALESCE`.. Its not getting from second one..

Comment: `COALESCE` will only get first not null value. that is why if you put Joining date from `Joined` table first and than list joining date from `Offered` table you will always get a value back.

Comment: If I execute the above query for the joined candidate means, it gets the date from `Hiring` table only.. Not from `Joining` table.. So, I changed to `COALESCE(j.JoiningDate, h.JoiningDate)`.. In this case it gets date from `Joining` table.. But if I execute for yet to join candidate means, it returns empty value, not from `Hiring` table..

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted, to get date for `Hiring` table if that is null than get date from `Joining` table.